# How to evaluate JavaScript with Firefox's Remote Debugging Protocol (RDP)?

Tags: javascript, firefox, webdriver, firefox-developer-tools

I am trying to use [RDP](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/devtools/backend/protocol.html) to automate Firefox, but I could not find a way to evaluate arbitrary JavaScript in the context of current web page. I am looking for a command equivalent to Chrome's [Runtime.evaluate](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/1-3/Runtime/#method-evaluate).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think Firefox is pursuing the implementation of CDP anymore, and as you already noticed, the `Runtime.evaluate` command does not seem to be part of the implemented features. Hard to be 100% sure because the available documentation is very sparse but I tested it and it fails with `UnknownMethodError`.

Mozilla is currently pushing for a new protocol: [WebdriverBiDi](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/remote/index.html#webdriver-bidi-header). This new specification should bridge the gap between the REST-based Webdriver protocol and the newly emerged Websocket-based DevTools protocol (more flexible and efficient). It will be a Websocket-based protocol and the good news is that Google, Mozilla, Apple and other major players are part of it. Hopefully, this will emerge as a real standard like Webdriver became.

Given the current draft of the spec, I would say that [`script.evaluate`](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver-bidi/#command-script-evaluate) should be the command you will be waiting for... I have no idea when it will get there though.